# Highcharts map bubble outline not displayed correctly

Tags: highcharts

I built a [map bubble](https://medien.lb.madsack.de/rnd/jchrist/coronalandkreise.html) with Highmaps. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/pq8gx0bn/15/)

```
series: {
type: 'mapbubble',
name: 'Infizierte',
zIndex: 10,
color: '#b30012',
minSize: '1',
maxSize: '12%',
crop: false,
states: {
  inactive: {
    opacity: 1
  }
},
marker: {
  fillOpacity: 0.1
        }
    }
```

The bubbles sometimes are not displayed correctly:
[image]

The outline is interrupted at the bottom. When I zoom in the gap is closed. Sometimes the mistake does not appear, sometimes it does. Does someone know why?

Comment: Hm... After digging there are my conclusions: The issue is related to the animation, which actually is delayed because the error occurred (check the console). Do you need the highcharts-more module? It is a reason of this error. Without it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9zn06aho/ another workaround is to set the animation.duration to some bigger value (JS will get extra time for download the data and do all operations). Demo:   https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pvLbscyo/

Comment: As an alternative consider to use the `markerClusters` feature: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/marker-clusters